# How did God resurrect Castiel if he has no power of the Empty?

Tags: supernatural

We know Chuck/God has resurrected Castiel on three occasions: when he was killed by Raphael in Season 4 (off screen), killed by Luficer (season 5), and when the Leviathans killed him after escaping from his body. 
In Season 13, we learn that angels go to the Empty when they die, and in season 13 episode 6, when Sam asks if Chuck resurrected him after his season 12 death, he said that God had no power of the Empty?

Does this not contradict the three previous times God resurrected Castiel*, not to mention that God is likely to be more powerful than an Archangel/Nephilim?

*Another time when Castiel was resurrected by Gadreel, he had become human, so I guess we can assume that he didn't go the Empty in this case.

Comment: As I can't answer this question yet (not enough reputation) the answer is clearer from the last season - Chuck brings back Lucifer even though he is in the Empty. Whether he has command over the Empty or just a good enough relation to ask for favours is not clear, but he can resurrect clearly

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the other times when Castiel died as an angel, God must have somehow prevented him from going to the Empty in the first place (as the Cosmic Entity does mention that nobody has ever escaped the Empty) before resurrecting him. However, this  implies that Jack has some power which God doesn't have, which doesn't seem correct, since he's the most powerful being we've seen on the show along with the Darkness.

Comment: Since nephilim become muuch stronger than the cosmic entity that paired with the human, I would not be surprised if Jack actually becomes stronger than god/darkness as he is the child of an archangel

Answer (score 0):

Would say in regards to Raphael if it happened off screen, it didn't happen. Likewise the Leviathans probably didn't "kill" him. More than likely between using their power along with the power of normal human souls allowed him to survive yet left him cosmic level traumatized. Which he was.

As for Luficer? During that fight Chuck had a ring side seat and likely "caught" Castiel just like he saved or brought back Bobby.

Answer (score -1):

This was exactly my question when this was stated on the show.
I have to agree with your own assumption. Chuck must have prevented Castiel from ever *going* to the Empty in the first place, as in he probably intervened before Cas' essence/grace left at all. 
How Jack managed to awaken him is another matter, since a creation of God should not logically be able to do things that he can't do, but that is another issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree that God must have prevented Castiel from going to the Empty in the first place the previous times. During the fight against the Darkness someone suggested that Chuck resurrect the archangels. He said that recreating them (I think that was the word he used) would be a difficult task. I suspect that he can’t resurrect the dead archangels if they are in the Empty... rather, he would be recreating them from scratch (basically a cosmic clone).

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn’t necessarily say that Jack has a power that Chuck doesn’t. Jack was able to reach Castiel and wake him up, but he didn’t pull him from the Empty... the cosmic entity sent him home. God may be able to wake his creations in the Empty but unable to send them home.

Comment: Is this answer supposed to be different to the one above? If not you should be [editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/174563/edit) the one above not making a new answer.